# MS Dynamics CRM 2013 - SSRS report get current id as parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report, crm

I have a custom entity which are "Sub-Accounts" of CRM entity "Accounts"
"Sub-Accounts" means subsidiaries of Accounts(Company)

I have a simple report on showing Details of "Sub-Accounts" (Single Subsidiary)

That's why, I add a parameter for filtering, every time user has to fill the "Sub Account Name" to filter the report.

Since I run the report on the "Sub-Account" page directly, I found that in the report URL, there are "id=..........." and "records=............." with a non-readable long text, and I found these long text in the database which is exactly the "id" of the current "Sub-Account"

I am wondering, if the id can be pass into the report as a default parameter, so that user do not have to fill the parameter themselves.

Please kindly advise if it is possible? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You will need to add a button to the "Sub-Accounts" ribbon and write some JavaScript to construct the URL and open that URL in a new window.  If you don't already have one, I would advise you to create a JavaScript webresource specifically for this entity, named something like subaccounts_main_library.js.  Paste the code below into the library, enter the name of your report and save/publish it.  When you add your button to the ribbon, the command needs to be setup to trigger the `runReport()` function.

You will also need to download the latest jQuery (2.1.1) and JSON2 libraries, then upload each of them as web resources.

```
function runReport() {
    openReport('<put the name of your report here>');
}

function openReport (reportName) {
    var oDataSetName = "ReportSet";
    var columns = "ReportId";
    var filter = "Name eq '" + reportName + "'";
    retrieveMultiple(oDataSetName, columns, filter, onSuccess);
    currReportName = reportName;
}

var currReportName;

function onSuccess (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();

    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
        var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
        var etc = Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters().etc;
        var entityId = id.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
        var reportId = data[0].ReportId.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
        var url = serverUrl + "/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&context=records&helpID=" + currReportName + ".rdl&id=%7b" + reportId + "%7d&records=%7b" + entityId + "%7d&recordstype=" + etc + "&p:InvoiceId=" + entityId;
        window.open(url, "reportwindow", "resizable=1,width=950,height=700");
    }
}

function retrieveMultiple(odataSetName, select, filter, successCallback) {

    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
    var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
    var odataUri = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName + "?";

    if (select) {
        odataUri += "$select=" + select + "&";
    }

    if (filter) {
        odataUri += "$filter=" + filter;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: odataUri,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            if (successCallback) {
                if (data && data.d && data.d.results) {
                    successCallback(data.d.results, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest);
                }
                else if (data && data.d) {
                    successCallback(data.d, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest);
                }
                else {
                    successCallback(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (XmlHttpRequest && XmlHttpRequest.responseText) {
                alert("Error while retrieval ; Error – " + XmlHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I can't take credit for the code above though.  We can thank Rajeev Pentyala for a great post on his blog. http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/opening-a-report-using-ribbon-button-in-crm-2011/

Hope this helps you out.  Let me know if you need any additional assistance.